# Find $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(Ax)e^{i\langle y,x \rangle}dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|dx<\infty$. Let $A$ be real $n\times n $ invertible matrix and for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\langle x,y\rangle$ denote the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(Ax)e^{i\langle y,x \rangle}dx=$

> (a)$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{i\langle (A^{-1})^Ty,x \rangle}\frac{dx}{|\det A|}$

> (b)$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{i\langle (A)^Ty,x \rangle}\frac{dx}{|\det A|}$

> (c)$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{i\langle (A^{T})^{-1}y,x \rangle}dx$

> (d)$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)e^{i\langle A^{-1}y,x \rangle}\frac{dx}{|\det A|}$

Make the change of variable $u=Ax$ then, $x=A^{-1}u$ and $\frac{du}{A}=dx$. Now,
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(Ax)e^{i\langle y,x \rangle}dx=
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(u)e^{i\langle y,A^{-1}u \rangle}\frac{du}{A}= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(u)e^{i\langle(A^{-1})^{T} y,u \rangle}\frac{du}{A}$

which doesn't match any option. I don't know if I am doing it right. Please help me to solve this question.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Do you have a guess as to what the answer is here?

Comment: Thank you. Seeing your ideas (even if they are wrong) is useful since it helps us figure out exactly needs to be explained.

Comment: Hi, @Omnomnomnom I just showed how I had attempted this question.

Comment: When doing change of variable, $\det(A)$ instead of $A$ should appear.

Comment: I don't know why that should happen @mathdoge. Could you please explain?

Comment: @s1mple Do you understand that in this context, $A$ is a matrix rather than a number? Have you taken a class in multivariate calculus or otherwise encountered the rule for [multivariate integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables)?

Comment: @s1mple I think that's the change of variable for higher dimension space. You could check it in Calculus book I think? One more fact is that if you define $g(x) := Ax$, then derivative of $g$ is $A$.

Comment: Yes, I have taken a course in multivariate calculus, and I do understand that $A$ is a matrix, but haven't encountered this, thanks for letting me know. This solves my query. Thanks for the help!